# Как остаться на той же JSP после выполнения submit в форме

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Пишу простое web-приложение на Java. Нужно после отправки формы в сервлет загрузить ту же JSP с добавлением сообщения об успехе/неуспехе выполнения метода в сервлете.

Каким способом можно остаться на той же JSP после нажатия submit и добавить при этом в эту JSP еще сообщение? Или такое невозможно сделать? Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в сервлете обработки submit-a, в случае ошибки добавить в request атрибут и сделать forward (RequestDispatcher) на ту же страницу.

Ну и в самой JSP:

```
<%=request.getAttribute("error")%>
```

Только проверить на null надо, иначе будет NPE.

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Чтобы не проверять NPE, в странице выводить не через скриплет, а средствами самой JSP: <p>${error}</p>

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець ничего что у блока `p` могут быть отступы типа padding или margin и если сделать так, как предложили Вы то этот блок будет всегда, а следовательно будет мешать пустым пространством

Comment: <p> это как пример. Юзайте любые тэги. Если в error приходит null, то никак не влияет. Я так делал у себя и видел недавно в туториалах. Могу поискать